# В чем ошибка с поведением?

Tags: yii2

**Пытаюсь создать свое первое поведение:**

```
use backend\modules\menus\behavior\MenuFrontendBehavior;

class Firmcat extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                [
                    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                    'attribute' => 'title',
                    'slugAttribute' => 'slug'
                ],
                'MenuFrontendBehavior' => [
                    'class' => MenuFrontendBehavior::className(),
                ]
             ]
        ];
    }
```

**Так пытаюсь получить его в контролере модуля:**

```
class Firmcat extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                [
                    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                    'attribute' => 'title',
                    'slugAttribute' => 'slug'
                ],
                'MenuFrontendBehaviors' => [
                    'class' => MenuFrontendBehavior::className(),
                    //'model' => 'yes',
                    //'prop2' => 'value2',* /
                ]
             ]
        ];
    }
```

**Выдает ошибку:**

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.
```

**Что я делаю не так?**

Comment: Проверьте как у вас написано слово "class", нередко туда могут попасть русские буквы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

был добавлен лишний массив одна пара [] была лишняя